# How to launch a link from datagridview image column?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datatable that I am binding to a datagrid in my vb.net app. I am trying to make one column a DataGridViewImageColumn. But I want to hide a URL in the column so that I can launch the URL when clicked. The URL is a column of the datatable but I dont think I am using the right type of column... little help should get me there.

Thanks